# create hammer.js "tap" function depending on top or bottom half of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hammer.js

i am trying to convert two "click" functions, into hammer.js "tap" functions instead. the idea is that tapping the bottom-half of the div does one thing--it should navigate to the next div; and tapping the top-half does another--it should navigate to the previous div.

here is the function working perfectly without hammer.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel').click(function(e) {
        // top
        if ($(this).outerHeight() / 2 > e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) {
            /* do something (go to PREV div) */
        }
        // bottom
        if ($(this).outerHeight() / 2 < e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) {
            /* do something (go to NEXT div) */
        }
    });
});
```

and here is a first attempt at the hammer.js tap conversion:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
    var element = document.getElementById('container');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on('tap', function(event) {
        alert('Tap!');
    })
}, false);
```

you can see, i have yet to split the hammer.js tap into the two separate functions. i have tried many different variations of using the same calculation as is in the top code to split the two activities, but it is either totally unresponsive, or hammer.js activates both activities concurrently.

i am a brand newbie at hammer.js (and javascript in general) and cannot figure out if i am erroneously mixing jquery with javascript, or am just having difficulty with hammer.js.

i should mention, however, that i have successfully created panleft, and panright, activities for the same site. and the reason i need to convert the "click" function to a "tap" function instead, is so that all gestures are handled by hammer.js, and not mixed--as the mixed gestures are making the site navigation too sensitive.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: per some of the help below, here is an attempt to incorporate the calculation into the tap function:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
    var element = document.getElementById('container');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on('tap', function(e) {
        if ($('.panel').outerHeight() / 2 > e.gesture.center.Y - $('.panel').offset().top) {
                alert('Top tap!');
        }
        if ($('.panel').outerHeight() / 2 < e.gesture.center.Y - $('.panel').offset().top) {
                alert('Bottom tap!');
        }
    })
}, false);
```

even using e.gesture.center.Y as a replacement for e.pageY--but to no avail. i still cannot get this work...

Comment: there's nothing wrong i can see with your js. Is there a reason why the second time you're not using jquery? if so, then you can use the plugin: https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js/blob/master/jquery.hammer.js

Comment: Are you using `e.gesture.center.pageX/pageY`? They are provided through the hammer event and might need to replace `e.pageY`.

Comment: i tried the jquery.hammer.js plugin as well, but nothing seemed to happen. truth be told, i am not entirely sure what to do with it beyond loading it into my index.html file. and i am not even sure if i put it in the correct location. there seems to be very little documentation for beginers.

Answer (score 0):

i've gotten this to work now:

```
var element = document.getElementById('panel');

$(element).hammer().on('tap', function(e) {
    if ($('#panel').outerHeight() / 2 > e.gesture.center.pageY - $('#panel').offset().top) {
        alert('Top tap!');
    }
    if ($('#panel').outerHeight() / 2 < e.gesture.center.pageY - $('#panel').offset().top) {
        alert('Bottom tap!');
    }
});
```

but only in hammer.js v1.0.5. i have opened a new question on what needs to change to make it work in v2.x.